# In groovy getting java.lang.NullPointerException while JSONPATH lookup

Tags: groovy

In java jsonpath using jayway we can suppress the exception while jsonpath lookup but is there any similar configuration available in groovy for jsonpath lookup.

Like for example:

```
import groovy.json.*;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText('{"test":{"test1":{"test2":{"test3":"1"}}}}')
print(object["test"]["test8"]["test9"]["d"])
```

So, as expected it will throw null pointer exception so, is there any way where we can configure to suppress exception and return null if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In groovy 3 you can apply null-safe operator also on bracketed elements:

```
print object?["test"]?["test8"]?["test9"]?["d"]
```

In groovy 2 and below you can use the `getAt()` to do safe-indexing:

```
print object?.getAt("test")?.getAt("test8")?.getAt("test9")?.getAt("d")
```